# How to get standard errors for ratios of means from a regression model with categorical treatments in R?

Tags: r, lm

I have some example data from an intercropping experiment, which consists of the yields of two crops A and B in monoculture and intercropped with each other. In this case, a crop in monoculture is expressed as an intercrop with itself, i.e.
crop A with crop A = monoculture; crop B with crop B = monoculture; crop A with crop B = intercrop; crop B with crop B = intercrop.

I would like to obtain a mean and SE for the land equivalence ratio, defined as:

*LER = (yield of crop A intercropped with B)/(yield of crop A in monoculture) + (yield of crop A
intercropped with B)/(yield of crop A in monoculture)*

It has been recommended that I use the delta method for the SE, so I think I want to use the `deltamethod()` function from `msm` (but not quite sure)

Here is the data (a subset of a larger experiment with more species):

```
structure(list(site = c("Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", 
"Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "One", "One", "One", 
"One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", 
"Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", 
"Three", "Three", "Three", "Three", "Three"), siteblock = c("Two_2", 
"Two_1", "Two_3", "Two_1", "Two_3", "Two_2", "Two_1", "Two_3", 
"Two_2", "Two_2", "Two_3", "Two_1", "One_2", "One_1", "One_3", 
"One_3", "One_1", "One_2", "One_3", "One_1", "One_2", "One_2", 
"One_3", "One_1", "Three_1", "Three_2", "Three_3", "Three_1", 
"Three_2", "Three_3", "Three_1", "Three_2", "Three_3", "Three_1", 
"Three_2", "Three_3"), species = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), pair = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B"), yield.pp = c(118.6648257, 80.29858998, 90.53153963, 
48.64188012, 140.3934164, 103.0518444, 18.23102298, 7.104490919, 
22.81524354, 21.07202039, 7.529486987, 18.63650567, 242.2567602, 
202.1431331, 185.5609192, 283.144789, 241.1690115, 241.5258056, 
23.78876862, 35.87524173, 41.1028137, 18.55380809, 22.46060419, 
18.46323056, 242.9551749, 231.387521, 455.9878777, 288.2237713, 
156.3390735, 207.4286019, 7.167311238, 34.66607289, 22.41394604, 
42.22510313, 38.70415176, 57.86653817)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

The experiment was replicated in three blocks at three sites, but let's ignore that for now for simplicity. I create a model to estimate the yield of each species in each combination:

```
mod<-lm(yield.pp~species*pair,data=df)
summary(mod)
```

Then it is straightforward to get estimated means for each crop in each combination:

```
est_grid<-data.frame(expand.grid(species=levels(as.factor(df$species)),pair=levels(as.factor(df$pair))))
est_means<-predict(mod,newdata=est_grid)
est_means
##        1         2         3         4 
##205.53182  23.68499 189.99091  27.27905
```

And to calculate the mean land equivalence ratio:

```
(est_means[3]/est_means[1])+(est_means[2]/est_means[4])
##       3 
##1.792635
```

So my question is how to obtain the SE to go with the mean ratio. I am currently stumped by `deltamethod` because it seems only to provide SEs for ratios of the estimated model parameters, rather than ratios of the estimated means ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the reference grid using ref_grid from emmeans in which case it will return an emmGrid object and that has a vcov method which is what is needed to run deltaMethod from the car package.

```
library(car)
library(emmeans)

r <- ref_grid(mod); r
## 'emmGrid' object with variables:
##     species = A, B
##     pair = A, B

s <- summary(r); s 
##  species pair prediction   SE df
##  A       A         205.5 23.7 32
##  B       A          23.7 23.7 32
##  A       B         190.0 23.7 32
##  B       B          27.3 23.7 32

m <- with(s, setNames(prediction, paste0(species, pair)))
##        AA        BA        AB        BB 
## 205.53182  23.68499 189.99091  27.27905 

deltaMethod(m, "AB / AA + BA / BB", vcov(r))
##               Estimate       SE    2.5 % 97.5 %
## AB/AA + BA/BB  1.79264  1.15910 -0.47916 4.0644
```

Comment: Really pleased with this delightfully simple solution, thank you. I assume if I include site in the model (for example) `mod<-lm(yield.pp~species*pair*site,data=df)` then `e<- emmeans(mod, ~species*pair)` followed by `m <- with(s, setNames(emmean, paste0(species, pair)))` and `deltaMethod(m, "AB / AA + BA / BB", vcov(e))` then that is doing exactly the same thing as `ref_grid` but generating an estimate averaged across sites?

Comment: Read the relevant vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is ratios, the **emmeans** package provides for them directly. The key is to re-grid the predictions to the log scale:

```
> rlog <- ref_grid(mod, transform = "log")
```

Or just use the reference grid from the other answer: `rlog <- regrid(r, "log")`.
Either way, we have converted to the reference grid as if a log transform had been applied. Use `type = "response"` to undo the log transformation:

```
> confint(rlog, type = "response")
 species pair response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A       A       205.5 23.7 32   162.58      260
 B       A        23.7 23.7 32     3.10      181
 A       B       190.0 23.7 32   147.43      245
 B       B        27.3 23.7 32     4.66      160

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

These are exactly the results obtained in @G.Grothendieck's answer. Now do pairwise comparisons; since differences of logs are logs of ratios, the back-transformation process produces ratios:

```
> pairs(rlog, type = "response", infer = c(TRUE, TRUE), adjust = "none")
 contrast  ratio    SE df lower.CL upper.CL null t.ratio p.value
 A A / B A 8.678 8.725 32   1.1194   67.268    1   2.149  0.0393
 A A / A B 1.082 0.183 32   0.7659    1.528    1   0.464  0.6460
 A A / B B 7.534 6.591 32   1.2682   44.763    1   2.309  0.0276
 B A / A B 0.125 0.125 32   0.0160    0.969    1  -2.069  0.0467
 B A / B B 0.868 1.148 32   0.0587   12.846    1  -0.107  0.9156
 A B / B B 6.965 6.102 32   1.1692   41.487    1   2.215  0.0340

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 
Tests are performed on the log scale
```

(I added the `infer` argument to get both CIs and tests.)

With some fancy maneuvering, it is even possible to answer the original question:

```
> con = contrast(rlog, list(`AB/AA` = c(-1,0,1,0), `BA/BB` = c(0,1,0,-1)))
> confint(con, type = "r")
 contrast ratio    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 AB/AA    0.924 0.157 32   0.6544     1.31
 BA/BB    0.868 1.148 32   0.0587    12.85

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 

> confint(contrast(regrid(con), list(`AB/AA + BA/BB` = c(1,1))))
 contrast      estimate   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 AB/AA + BA/BB     1.79 1.16 32   -0.568     4.15

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

The confidence limits differ slightly because we use 32 d.f. while `deltaMethod` produces asymptotic results (infinite d.f.)