# How to use a transformed reference grid in emmeans from a nested model?

Tags: r, emmeans

I have been trying to use a log-transformed reference grid to obtain pairwise mean ratios with `emmeans` (following a suggested solution to a previous problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650393/how-to-get-standard-errors-for-ratios-of-means-from-a-regression-model-with-cate/68697505#68697505)).

However, I have a nested model, I can't work out how to get the functions `confint` and `pairs` to work on a log-transformed reference grid that is created from a nested model. Here is an example using the nested example from the [emmeans messy data vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/messy-data.html):

```
cows <- data.frame (
  route = factor(rep(c("injection", "oral"), c(5, 9))),
  drug = factor(rep(c("Bovineumab", "Charloisazepam", 
                      "Angustatin", "Herefordmycin", "Mollycoddle"), c(3,2,  4,2,3))),
  resp = c(34, 35, 34,   44, 43,      36, 33, 36, 32,   26, 25,   25, 24, 24)
)

cows.lm <- lm(resp ~ route + drug, data = cows)
cows.lrg <- ref_grid(cows.lm, transform="log")
#NOTE: A nesting structure was detected in the fitted model:
#    drug %in% route

confint(cows.lrg, type="response")
#Error in object@linfct[use.elts, , drop = FALSE] : 
#  (subscript) logical subscript too long

pairs(cows.lrg, type = "response", infer = c(TRUE, TRUE), adjust = "none")
#Error in x@linfct[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `rlog`? Unless I'm blind, I don't see where you have defined it

Comment: Oops sorry - you are not blind, but apparently I am! I had copied the wrong code... edited now.

Comment: I meanwhile posted an answer; and updated it so it makes sense relative to your revised question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have discovered there is a bug in the `regrid()` function. If you even do `summary(cows.lrg)`, you get an error.
The problem is that nested structures may involve some "phantom" rows in the reference grid that are not preserved with `regrid()`. Here is a way to hack around it, but it isn't pretty:

```r
cows.lrg@linfct = matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
cows.lrg@linfct[cows.rg@misc$display, ] = diag(5)
cows.lrg@misc$display = as.logical(cows.lrg@grid$.wgt.)
```

Now we have

```r
> summary(cows.lrg)
 route     drug           prediction SE df
 oral      Angustatin           3.53 NA  9
 injection Bovineumab           3.54 NA  9
 injection Charloisazepam       3.77 NA  9
 oral      Herefordmycin        3.24 NA  9
 oral      Mollycoddle          3.19 NA  9

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
```

Unfortunately, we still don't have valid covariance values, making the SE's all `NA`.

I will work on fixing this, and update it on the GitHub repository for **emmeans**. It may take a while; and unfortunately, I just this morning uploaded an update of the package to CRAN, which, by Murphy's Law of Bad Timing, does not have a fix for this.

Comment: Thanks!! Looking forward to the update on GitHub, and it's helpful to have the little hack in the meantime to get on with the predictions.

Comment: @corn_bunting I created an [issue for this on GitHub](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/287) -- so refer to that. I believe I have it fixed, and you can install the update using the instructions on the Code page. Oddly, this will be an update to version 1.6.3, which hasn't yet appeared on CRAN. If CRAN rejects 1.6.3 for some reason, I'll incorporate these changes too.

Comment: Brilliant - I have installed it and it works, thanks for fixing it so fast. I still have an issue with getting ratios rather than differences from the contrasts for the nested variable (i.e. `pairs(emmeans(cows.lrg,~drug),type="r")` rather than `pairs(emmeans(cows.lrg,~route),type="r")` but will post this to my previous question where it is more relevant. Probably an issue with my understanding rather than with the function.

Comment: You probably want `~ drug | route`

Comment: I tried both of those and they work fine for me. Maybe you have an old version of `cows.lrg` that was made before the update.

Comment: Oh I've got it: the `type="r"` argument has to go inside the `emmeans` function not the `pairs` function. So `pairs(emmeans(cows.lrg,~drug|route,type="r"))` works, but `pairs(emmeans(cows.lrg,~drug|route),type="r")` does not. I assume this is intentional...

Comment: OK, I verified that `type = "r"` doesn't work correctly the second way. It'll be fixed the next time I push an update to GitHub.